# How to set the name of output title to match input?

Tags: gnuplot

So I have a bash script that takes name of input file and then pipes it to gnuplot script. Now I am stuck with script failing because it expects output to be STRING.

> internal error : STRING operator applied to undefined or non-STRING variable

bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter the filename to plot:"
read filename
cat $filename | gnuplot script.gplot
```

gnuplot script:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
set output filename . 'png'
set term pngcairo enhanced size 1024, 768
plot '<cat' u 1:2
```

Now I input file name x-1.txt and it fails. Is there an option to tell output to just use the name from input?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter filename:"
read filename
export GNUTERM="pngcairo size 1024,768"
gnuplot $filename.gplot > $filename.png
```

Comment: this doesn't work. You don't call the gnuplot script with it and even adding the script still fails

Comment: I did a bit of change to my code according to yours anwser @Ethan. Removed the set output from script and added just > $filename.png to my script with the export GNUTERM you put it in. And now it works, thanks on idea!